# Spring Boot 2.x Connection Factory

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the below class that works well in Spring Boot 1.5.x

```
public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        org.springframework.data.jdbc.config.oracle.AqJmsFactoryBeanFactory f=new AqJmsFactoryBeanFactory();
        f.setDataSource(dataSource);
        f.setCoordinateWithDataSourceTransactions(true);
        f.setNativeJdbcExtractor(new org.springframework.jdbc.support.nativejdbc.Jdbc4NativeJdbcExtractor());
        f.setConnectionFactoryType(ConnectionFactoryType.QUEUE_CONNECTION);
        try {
            return f.getObject();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

I have now upgraded to 2.0.4 version where NativeJdbcExtractor is not present. Can someone help me how to reconfgure the above to get the connectionFactory.

Answer (score 0):

The whole nativejdbc hierarchy doesn't exists anymore and what isn't there anymore cannot be used.So either don't upgrade or figure out a way to not need it (jdbc 4 can use unwrap to get the actual underlying connection).

To get the actual underlying connection there is an unwrap method on the Connection. So something along the lines of `connection.unwrap(OracleConnection.class)` should get you the actual underlying connection. However that might require an additional upgrade of the aq-jms-connection-factory which I'm not certain supports Spring 5.0.

Comment: After a bit of analysis, I found that the below code would work but the error still remains the same.                                                                                                              Bean
   public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() throws JMSException {
  return AQjmsFactory.getQueueConnectionFactory(dataSource,true);
 }

Comment: What error? Your question doesn't state anything about an exception.

Comment: Sorry, that's a typo I am basically using the above code read contents from Oracle queue. The error I meant was the queue is not getting read.

Answer (score 0):

I have used something like this which can help you :

```
public OracleConnection getOracleConnection(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
    OracleConnection oconn = null;
    try {
        if (connection.isWrapperFor(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class)) {
            oconn = (OracleConnection) connection.unwrap(oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.class)._getPC();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw e;
    }
    return oconn;
}
```

Comment: There are no errors it didn't pick the contents from the oracle queue.